# What is the name of this neural network architecture with layers that are also connected to non-neighbouring layers?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, feedforward-neural-networks, residual-networks

Consider a feedforward neural network. Suppose you have a layer of inputs, which is feedforward to a hidden layer, and feedforward both the input and hidden layers to an output layer.  Is there a name for this architecture? A layer feeds forward around the layer after it?

Comment: How are you combining the two layers - concatenating the two vectors to make one longer vector size num_imputs + num_hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be called a [residual neural network (ResNet)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf), which is a neural network with skip connections, that is, connections that skip layers.

Here's a screenshot of a figure from the paper [Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) (2015), an important paper that shows the usefulness of these architectures.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Such a network could be either a **Residual Network** or a **Highway Network** depending upon the underlying architecture of the skip layers. They are primarily used to to tackle the problem of vanishing gradients in very deep networks by reusing activations from a previous layer and passing them to adjacent layers (two or three skips away).

- **Highway Network**: ([Training Very Deep Networks, 2015](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5850-training-very-deep-networks))

$z$ acts as a *Gating Function*, which controls how much information is to be transmitted from a previous layer in the network. An additional weight matrix is used to estimate the skip weights.[image: Highway]

- **Residual Network**:[(Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition ,2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf)

This architecture does not involve a Gate Controller. The shortcut connections are realized by adding the outputs of a previous layer to that of the connecting layer.

[image: Residual]